# How to expand a geographical square by 500 meters?

Tags: c#, geolocation, geocoding, geography

Let say I have a geographical square/rectangle where I have lat/lon definitions of the Northwest and Southeast corners.

I'd like to expand this square rectangle by 500 meters in each direction.  What is the approach I should take? An example would be great.

P.S. Earth is not flat, as some would have us believe, so I am willing to live with the approximate model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the conversion from minutes and seconds of arc to meters, convert, add, and convert back.

Edit: The circumference of the Earth in meters is ~40,000,000 (original definition of meter).  Since it looks like you need a solution for an arbitrary rectangle, assume a sphere and then 360 * 500 / 40,000,000 = 0.0045 degrees = 16.2 arc seconds is what you need to add to each side.

Answer (score 1):

Lat/long to distance is done with the [Haversine](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) formula, but I don't think it's trivial to invert. For such a short distance, though, you can probably get away with calculating the distance in metres of a second of arc at your given latitude, and multiply up appropriately.